# Open a document in sheet2 of a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which once assigned to a button and is clicked opens up a .dat file for me.

However, this opens the file on a separate workbook and I want to be able to open in so that it shows in Sheet2 of the same workbook.

My code is:

```
Sub Open_Workbook()

    Dim my_FileName As Variant

    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename

    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly, but this will open it, copy all the data into sheet 2 and then close the dat file without saving

```
Sub Open_Workbook()

    Dim my_FileName As Variant

    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename

    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
        activeworkbook.sheets(1).usedrange.copy thisworkbook.sheets(2).range("a1")
        activeworkbook.close false
    End If

End Sub
```